# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, android, classpath

I am using an API from Mashape in an Android application. Mashape recommends using the Unirest library. I have included the dependencies mentioned on the unirest link: http://unirest.io/java

My Dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile group:'com.mashape.unirest', name:'unirest-java', version:'1.3.26'
compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpcore', version:'4.3.3'
compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpclient', version:'4.3.6'
compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpasyncclient', version:'4.0.2'
compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpmime', version:'4.3.5'
compile group:'org.json', name:'json', version:'20141113'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

I still get this error when I make a HTTPRequest:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:153)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:133)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58805', transport: 'socket'

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

My java code is simple:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://testlink/all")
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", TEST_KEY)
                    .asJson();
```

Could you please help me solve this issue? Thanks for your help!

---

**UPDATE:**
As per secondo's suggestion I changed the httpclient to httpclient-android. My dependencies look like this now:

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group:'com.mashape.unirest', name:'unirest-java', version:'1.3.26'
    compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpclient-android', version:'4.3.5'
    compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpcore', version:'4.3.3'
    compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpcore-nio', version:'4.3.3'
    compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpasyncclient', version:'4.0.2'
    compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpmime', version:'4.3.5'
    compile group:'org.json', name:'json', version:'20141113'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

After rebuilding the project and running it, I get this error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    H:\IDEs\Android\android-sdk\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-4bcf10ca50c0eb5fadc28458c4bdfc2547896050.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-5f3630f6ee4db4f375d08625dd3729b85011cca4.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpasyncclient-4.0.2-5690889a573efdb127c3d5c2454e7a393211dee6.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpclient-android-4.3.5-1f1bd070e63b095d84e38ae09b61037bfca0f0ab.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpcore-4.3.3-ee2fa72794df9164a47403637dad2f0f578b8086.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpcore-nio-4.3.3-a277a34ed4caa7515de7b22c51b9b5f43eb3a9ac.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\httpmime-4.3.5-ed96b5f192c9ed4e3cca5097f8fe8a3d2a673970.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.0-529c245f53e03251f5328b23447088bd0d76c596.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.0-bc18e9201600d41ee5718ce129ef80828a7bb5d5.jar H:\workspace\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\unirest-java-1.3.26-7ee6377b956e1b237982bd82965679bf6e0a7fa9.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager` it means you forgot some jar files needed i think.

Comment: Hi Secondo. I added all the dependencies. Could you please tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: to be honest I only have few knowledge about android but have you ever tried to include [This?](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpclient-android%7C4.3.5%7Cjar)

Answer (score 2):

there is no class file in your project for following classe.

```
org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
```

So please add jar file in your project library you can downalod this jar file from below link

[Download Jar File](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpclient/httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar.zip)

Comment: `compile group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name:'httpclient', version:'4.3.6'` based on this i think he has already included that jar file and you are suggesting a lower version of it.

Comment: @Secondo Can you please try to add above jar file mention in my answer and build your app and try.

Comment: @Secondo your code has only `org.apache.httpcomponents` but you are getting error of `org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager`. So try above jar file and test.

Comment: I cant :) i tried to download the link you gave and it is version 4.3-beta1.jar but the OP already have 4.3.6 in his classpath .  is there any problem with 4.3.6 version ?

Comment: @Secondo Are you sure the same jar has been imported in your project. Does your previous jar has class `org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager'?

Comment: Also you can download other version from here:- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient43beta1jar.htm

Comment: btw Im not the one who ask the question XD im just also suggesting some idea. **based** on this `your code has only org.apache.httpcomponents but you are getting error of org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager.` you are implying that im the one who is ask it :P.   just to make it clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66084/discussion-between-miya-g-and-secondo).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.

Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.